# Virtualbox fails to launch on Juno

Tags: virtualbox, release-juno

When launching virtualbox, the icon appears in the launcher and disappears. Virtualbox does not open. In the terminal, I run it and get this:

```
VirtualBox: Error -610 in supR3HardenedMainInitRuntime!
VirtualBox: dlopen("/usr/lib/virtualbox/VBoxRT.so",) failed: <NULL>

VirtualBox: Tip! It may help to reinstall VirtualBox.
```

I've tried reinstalling. I've done this too:

```
sudo chown root:root /usr 
sudo chown root:root /usr/lib
```

Any help is appreciated. Thank you

The result of ls -la /usr

```
drwxr-xr-x  10 root root  4096 Oct  3 10:20 .
drwxr-xr-x  24 root root  4096 Dec 14 17:41 ..
drwxrwxrwx   2 root root 69632 Jan 28 19:29 bin
drwxrwxrwx   2 root root  4096 Oct 30 19:41 games
drwxrwxrwx  44 root root  4096 Nov 25 10:51 include
drwxrwxrwx 146 root root 12288 Jan 28 19:29 lib
drwxrwxrwx  10 root root  4096 Oct  3 10:20 local
drwxrwxrwx   2 root root 12288 Dec 17 19:36 sbin
drwxrwxrwx 318 root root 12288 Jan 28 19:29 share
drwxrwxrwx  11 root root  4096 Jan 28 19:29 src
```

Comment: This is likely caused by this https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/16759

-- If you chowned the /usr/* directories before, perhaps you did so recursively. Can you confirm /usr/* has original permissions?

Comment: Like a noob, I didn't check to see what they were originally. Currently they are at 751 (drwxr-xr-x)?

Comment: But you didn't change the ownership before? What's the output of `ls -la /usr`?

Comment: That didn't paste well, but `/usr/*` directories are owned as root, like normal? You didn't do anything in the past that might have changed them?

Comment: Guess you can tell this is my first stackexchange post

Comment: I only made changes from suggested posts after vbox didnt open

Comment: What permissions should /usr be?

Answer (score 0):

technicallyblue,

Welcome to the forum.  Ken Kinder's comment was spot on the mark.  I am running VBox  5.2.18_Ubuntu r123745 (with extension pack) on Juno -- no problems (so far).

However, your stated POSIX permissions on your /usr directory you stated were (751).  From the directory listing you gave they appear to be (777).  That does **not** match my fresh installation of Juno.

Performing a chmod on the entire /usr directory is **not** recommended.  I highly urge you to reset it to 755 as soon as possible. That command would be:

```
sudo chmod -R 755 /usr
```

You have already set the /usr and /usr/lib folder owner to root (which is the correct user).  After the chmod command has finished, I recommend a *reboot*.  After the reboot, completely uninstall virtualbox and all of its settings with the following command:

```
sudo apt purge virtualbox
```

Then you can reinstall Virtualbox the usual way (AppCenter or sudo apt install virtualbox).  Good luck!  If you continue to experience odd problems, it may be necessary to reinstall Juno.  However, don't jump through those hoops unless you are forced to do so...

Comment: Thank you for the response. I thought people gave up on me! I solved the first problem by finding an old link that instructs the user to add themselves to the vboxusers group. Now I have a brand new error one virtual box starts and I try to run a new vm or run an existing vm. <br/> 
`The virtual machine 'Arch' has terminated unexpectedly during startup with exit code 1 (0x1).` <br/>


`Result Code: 
NS_ERROR_FAILURE (0x80004005)
Component: 
MachineWrap
Interface: 
IMachine {5047460a-265d-4538-b23e-ddba5fb84976}`

Comment: try running this command in Teminal: `modinfo vboxdrv` Does the version of the kernel module match the application version of VirtualBox (located at Help -> About VirtualBox...)?

Comment: Yes it does
`modinfo vboxdrv`
`filename:       /lib/modules/4.15.0-45-generic/misc/vboxdrv.ko`
`version:        6.0.4 r128413 (0x00290008)`
`license:        GPL`
`description:    Oracle VM VirtualBox Support Driver`
`author:         Oracle Corporation`
`srcversion:     6459061BFB65420ED835769`
`depends:`
`retpoline:      Y`
`name:           vboxdrv`
`vermagic:       4.15.0-45-generic SMP mod_unload `
`parm:           force_async_tsc:force the asynchronous TSC mode (int)`

Comment: Although version 6.0.4 is the most current version (in series 6.x) version 5.2 is still supported.  I chose AppCenter to install VirtualBox on Elementary OS.  It installed version 5.2.18 (most current version in 5.2.x is 5.2.26).  I would recommend that you (1) uninstall VirtualBox 6.0.4 and then (2) reboot. (3) Use AppCenter to install 5.2.18.  Then (4) install the VirtualBox_Extension_Pack-5.2.18.vbox-extpack (available from (virtualbox.org).

Comment: I'm going to do a reinstall of Juno. I'm back to where I started and I ruined my permissions on a great many folders.

Comment: you ruined my sudo permissions and destroyed my linux. now i have to reinstall my juno thanks to you K. Capwell.